# Why does Infovis JS Toolkit crash in Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, extjs, infovis

I'm using the Infovis JS toolkit inside an EXT JS Container. Now in Chrome the site crashes without giving me any hint why it does. Other browsers work well.

I made a little demo site http://dev.eftas.com:8080/idnetwork/

The annoying thing is, that I have no clue how to debug this crashing as it seems to be appearing randomly. Also the console isnt't attached to the website any more after the crash.

EDIT: Chrome: 37.0.2062.124, OS X 10.9.5 (but also occurs on Windows based machines)

Any help is highly appreciated!

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: Chrome version? Operating system?

Comment: Sorry.
Chrome: 37.0.2062.124
OS: OS X 10.9.5

But it occurs on latest Windows Versions as well. Seems to be a Chrome problem